# Flutter - Layout in the Emulator & Phones are different

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm making a new project in Flutter. Every widget that i made is work perfectly.. but there's some issue when i want to place **two images Container in Row**, it's perfectly fine on Emulator with 1080x1920, but when i open it on my 460x854 phone...it's crashing with the Symmetric Padding. I've reading some about **MediaQuery**, but because i'm a beginner, i can't implement it.

Can someone help me?

Here is the code(the full code is too long):

```
return new Scaffold(
    body: ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    new Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: Column(
               children: <Widget>[
               //sdsds
                new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: Row(
                         //HERE IS THE IMAGE IN ROW
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Container(
                            height: 160.0,
                            width: 160.0,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage('intro/1pew.png'),
                            )),
                          ),
                          new Container(
                            height: 160.0,
                            width: 160.0,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage('intro/2pew.png'),
                            )),
```

Here is the screenshot (**btw, ignore those pewds**):

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than set the height and width. I would use a `Row`, then add `Expanded` widgets, with `AspectRatio` childs to force behaviour.

example:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 1,
            child: Image.asset("assets/image1.png"),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 1,
            child: Image.asset("assets/image2.png"),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

This forces both items in the `Row` to be the same size as both `Expanded` the `AspectRatio` widget will force a square, then your view can fill that square.

Answer (score 0):

For perfect responsiveness on mobile phones and tablets, you have to determine the hight and width both:

```
final constraint =  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width +
 MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

 Image.asset(
   "assets/image.png",
     width: constraints * 0.2,
     height: constraints * 0.4,
  ),

 Text( 
 title, 
 style: TextStyle(
 fontSize: constraints * 0.012,),),
```

Answer (score -1):

for detail about [mediaquery](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html)

to use media query

```
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
```

for screen adjustment you can add

```
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/number (e.g 2 or 3, whatever),
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
```